# What is the set of $\sup\{x\geq 1/2: (x-\frac{1}{2})^2+1\leq \log 3\}$?

Tags: calculus

What is the set of 
$$\sup\{x\geq 1/2: (x-\frac{1}{2})^2+1\leq \log 3\}$$

It seems that for any $x\geq 1/2$, $\sup {(x-\frac{1}{2})^2+1}=1\leq \log 3$. So what is the sup?

Comment: If $\sup \in SET$ then $\sup$ and $\max$ are the same thing.  But if $\sup \not \in SET$ then $\max$ does not exist.  The *only* difference between $\sup$ and $\max$ is that if the least upper bound is an element of the set that $\sup =\max =$ the least upper bound.  But if the least upper bound is not an element of the set then $\max$ does not exist and $\sup = $ the least upper bound.

Comment: So the question is... Does the set have a maximum element.  If so what is it.  If the set doesn't have a maximum element is the set bounded above if so, what is the least upper bound that high elements "tend to".

Comment: @fleablood what I want to ask is not the differential between max and sup. I just want to know what is the sup of that set?

Comment: " I just want to know what is the sup of that set? "  Well, what do you *THINK* it is.  You said it seemed to exist.  SO what do you think it is?

Comment: @fleablood That set should be the sup of $s$. But we do just know the lower bound for $S\geq 1/2$... It seems that we cannot know the upper bound from the restriction $(s-1/2)^2+10\leq 3$.

Comment: I think you need to review your text and relearn the definitions of bounded sets, upper bounds of sets, and the sup = least upper bound of a set.  You questions show such a weak understanding of the concepts I don't see how I can help you without reteaching you everything from the very beginning.... To begin with a sup is a value and can not be a set.  so "That set should be the sup of s"  simply does not make any sense at all.

Comment: If $(x-\frac 12)^2 + 10 \le \log 3$ then $(x-\frac 12)^2 \le \log 3 - 10 < 0$.  That is impossible.  So the set is empty.  And empty set does not have $\sup$.

Comment: @fleablood That should be $+1$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am editting my answer since the OP made a mistake and edited his question. Since $x \geq \frac{1}{2}$ then $(x-\frac{1}{2})^2 \geq 0$ but $(x-\frac{1}{2})^2+1 \leq ln(3)$. the sup exists and is equal to the largest value of x on the interval $[\frac{1}{2}, \sqrt{ln3-1} + \frac{1}{2}]$ thus the sup is equal to the upper bound of the interval $\sqrt{ln3-1} + \frac{1}{2}$

Comment: Sorry for the mistake, that should be $+1$ not $10$.

Comment: Well then, what is the base of log, is it natural log or base 10?

Comment: It is natural log.

Comment: if it's log with a base higher than 3 than it is still correct.

Comment: Well then my answer is incorrect then.

Comment: No.. I just want to let $(x-1/2)^2+1\leq \log 3$ hold.

Comment: it does hold, since $1 < ln3$

Comment: Take $\sqrt{ln3}+\frac{1}{2}$ that is your supremum.

Comment: Why do you get this sup? Can you give me more details? Thanks.

Comment: That is the largest value x can take  on this interval. take $(x-\frac{1}{2})^2 = ln(3)$ then rearrange for x, I am assuming x is an element of the reals yes?

Comment: You are looking for the largest value of x s.t. it satisfies that inequality and is greater than 1/2

Comment: Well, the max of $(x-1/2)^2$ is zero, so how do you take this one $ln 3$?

Comment: the max is not 0 $x\geq \frac{1}{2}$ right? that means x can be any number on the interval $[\frac{1}{2},\infty)$ also I made a mistake before because I forgot about the 1, that means the supremum is equal to $\sqrt{ln3-1}+\frac{1}{2}$

Comment: I believe you are thinking that x must be $\frac{1}{2}$ but according to what you wrote it can be any number larger than that as long as $(x-1/2)^2<ln3$